# how to Call JSON web service in the browser

Tags: json, web-services, browser

i have a web service that returns JSON string, and i wanna call this web service in the browser directly without using "Invoke" , and this is the formate i use to call ,,

```
http://localhost/WebserviceAliasonIIS/serviceName.asmx/FunctionName
```

what am i doing wrong cuz it keep return an error on the browser

and this is the error message

Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/FunctionName'.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind every one, my bad ,, i found out i forgot to but this is the web.Config file

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
</system.web>
```